# How can I execute external commands from the gdb command prompt?

Tags: gdb

I am debugging a program using gdb.  Whenever I miss a breakpoint or decide to add another watchpoint, I have to kill the process and rerun it.  In order to attach the existing gdb to it, I use `attach <pid>`.  However, I have to find out the pid of the new process.

The way I do that today is to suspend gdb, get the pid with `ps -C <program_name>` and then return to gdb to attach to it.

Is there any way to run a unix command from the gdb command prompt without exiting to the shell, so that I could do something like this from inside gdb:

```
attach `ps -C <program_name>`
```

I am working on linux.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> (gdb) help shell
>   Execute the rest of
>   the line as a shell command. With no
>   arguments, run an inferior shell.

After finish, you can use 'exit' to return to gdb.

Comment: is there a way to use the output of the shell command in a gdb command without copying?
attach shell ps -C <program_name>
doesn't seem to work for me, so I can only do
shell ps -C <program_name>
<copy the output>
attach <paste>

but it would be great if there was a better option

Comment: in my case I need to shell to a ssh command to get the .text address of a kernel module so I can tell the local gdb to load symbols for that address, being able to take the result of a script and run it as a gdb command would make this super easy.

Comment: 2021 and looking for the same. I'd be happy enough if I could display the output of a shell-command called in a "define".

Answer (score 23):

```
gdb$ shell

shell$ execute_your_commands 

shell$ exit

gdb$ you_have_returned_back_to_gdb_prompt
```

Answer (score 15):

You can just use `shell` followed by the command you want to execute, e.g.:

```
gdb$ shell g++ tsort.c -o tsort
```

This is just a short form of the previous answer.

Comment: In this mode gdb does not seem to pick up or be able to report problems when there is core dump.

Answer (score 7):

Just to expand on the accepted answer, the shortcut for `shell` is `!`.

> (gdb) help !
>
> Execute the rest of the line as a shell command. With no arguments,
>   run an inferior shell.