# How to run an external command from lldb prompt

Tags: lldb

Does lldb have an equivalent for gdb's `shell` command to run external commands from the prompt? (see [How can I execute external commands from the gdb command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297534/how-can-i-execute-external-commands-from-the-gdb-command-prompt))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for...

```
(lldb) help platform shell
     Run a shell command on a the selected platform.  This command takes 'raw'
     input (no need to quote stuff).

Syntax: platform shell <shell-command>

Command Options Usage:
  platform shell [-t <value>]

       -t <value> ( --timeout <value> )
            Seconds to wait for the remote host to finish running the command.

IMPORTANT NOTE:  Because this command takes 'raw' input, if you use any
     command options you must use ' -- ' between the end of the command options
     and the beginning of the raw input.
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case I'm using this for rebuilding an app from the terminal before re-launching the debugger, so the syntax is ` pla sh -t 100 -- make -j3 <target>` for example. The `-t` argument is needed since the default timeout is quite short and the `--` is needed as per the note in the help output.

Answer (score 1):

`(lldb) platform shell ls`

If you get:

`error: unable to run a remote command without a platform`

Try this command to see if you need to give lldb more context:

`(lldb) platform status`

If you are debugging on a real iOS ARM device, this will show `Platform: remote-ios`.  If you are on a simulator, you will get your macOS related info.